# Xoom 2 ME speakers stopped working

Tags: bugs, motorola-xoom

My Xoom 2 ME is running ICS 4.0.4 (rooted), and a week ago the speakers just stopped working. Lost the hour to go to work twice because alarm clock did not go.

Googling around seems to show some people also having problem with the speakers of the tablet running that particular version of android...

Some are just the subwoofer, others the orientation, but mine went completely mute. The sound still comes out of the headphones jack.

**Is there a fix for this, if its a software malfunction?**

---

Also, why can't Motorola make a proper ROM?
(this one is just to vent some steam, don't answer that)

> ```
> Retag as Xoom2-ME because I am still somewhat short of rep to do it. Delete this line afterwards, thanks.
> ```

Comment: In case someone has the same problem as I had, here's to Google indexing this page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Motorola really did a shitty job of patching the ICS rom for the Xoom2 ME. the IR blaster didn't work for a couple months, and this speaker bug is indeed software.

There is an app by [Wyrm](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=wyrm) on the Play Store that fix some of the speakers issues:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=wms.xoom2mespeakersfix

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=wms.xoom2mespeakersfixfree

It needs root. If your problem is fixed by the app, send some dough the dev's way by buying the donationware paid version.

Also thanks to the team behind the http://xoom2me.blogspot.com.br/ blog for the savior post.